# Format string attack, difference between %_$d and %d

Tags: c, security, printf, format-string

I'm currently getting into binary exploitation, so far so good.

The only thing that I don't really understand is the difference between %4$d and %4d, for example. I was looking at this guide:

http://www.kroosec.com/2012/12/protostar-format2.html

and, on the last line, '*minimum field width*' is mentioned while %60d is used. Is this related to my question? When should one use %$d and when %d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar sign inside a format string indicates a position of the variable used in printf. In this way, you may for example have only 1 parameter to the function, but use it 10 times in your format string, or with more parameters, in a different order. Depending on the programming language, you may or may not use mixed $ formatting.